# Where i can find my pages cshtml after Deploy in NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, web-deployment, .net-6.0

I am developing a website in asp.net mvc with NET 6 and when I deploy I cannot find anymore the cshtml pages, but a lot of folders, dll and an .exe.

The problem is that it looks like I need to update all the website each time I modify one single page.

Is there a way to put online only the modified page cshtml without deploying the entire website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***1. You need add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package.***

***2. You also need Copy the cshtml when you deploy.***

So my .csproj  file like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="6.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ViewFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)\Views\**\*.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <Target Name="CopyViewFilesAfterPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ViewFiles)"
      DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\Views\%(RecursiveDir)"
    />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

---

**Test Result:**

1. Find cshtml file in publish file.

[image]

2. Test in IIS

[image]

Comment: Hi Jason, it means that if i install the package : "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation " i will be able to update only the views (in case of only html modification) or do i still need to build all the the project?

Comment: @TamilCantroz You can modify your cshtml directly, don't need to redeploy. But I don't suggest you to this in your production app.